# Got classcastexception and resolved after server restart. Is there any specific reason for this?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am supporting a J2EE based insurance application. Last week, we had a classcast exception which got resolved after server restart without any modification to the program. I'm very interested to know what could be the cause for this error and resolution. There was no updates in terms of Java, weblogic sever or any other programs linked to the application. All of sudden it raised and disappeared after server restart.

Feel free to ask if you need any info from my side to answer this.

Thanks,
Bhavanam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a classloading conflict and depending on which order the libraries are loaded, it works or does not (results may change each restart)

You can check your application for classloading conflicts with the integrated classloading analysis tool (it is deployed in development mode automatically). http://host:port/wls-cat

See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG495

Comment: Thanks slettal. I will take it up with my DBA team